# При клике на кнопку воспроизвести клик на другой элемент

Tags: javascript

Нужно при клике на button вызвать событие trigger или click в class="item-text".

```js
 $('.items button').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.items').find('.item-img').click(function() {
     alert($(this).text());
  });
});
```

```css
.item-content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="items">
  <button>Button 1</button>
  <div class="item-content">
    <div class="item-text">
      Item text 1
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="items">
  <button>Button 2</button>
  <div class="item-content">
    <div class="item-text">
      Item text 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.items .item-text').click(function() {
  alert("click on .item-text - " + $(this).text());
});

$('.items button').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.items').find('.item-text').click();
});
```

```css
.item-content {
  /*display: none;*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="items">
  <button>Button 1</button>
  <div class="item-content">
    <div class="item-text">
      Item text 1
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="items">
  <button>Button 2</button>
  <div class="item-content">
    <div class="item-text">
      Item text 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const button = document.querySelector("button");
const itemText = document.querySelector(".item-text");

itemText.onclick = ()=>console.log("item-text clicked!");

button.addEventListener("click",()=>itemText.onclick());
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <button>Button 1</button>
  <div class="item-content">
    <div class="item-text">
      Item text 1
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```